# How can I capture a numeric input from an HTML doc and save it as a numeric value in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class = "input">
    <b>Weight </b><input type = '' id = 'weight' value = '180'>
</div>
<script>
    let weight = document.getElementById('weight');
    console.log(weight/2.205);
</script>
```

The output is NaN. Is there a solution that will convert 'weight' into the proper value? Thank you for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
let weight = parseInt(document.getElementById('weight').value);
console.log(weight/2.205);
```

```html
<div class = input>
    <b>Weight </b><input type="text" id='weight' value = '180' />
</div>
```

You were referring to wrong variable `weight` instead of `height`

`document.getElementById('weight')` will give you the element reference not the value.

To get the value you need to use the `.value` attribute `document.getElementById('weight').value`

Input box will always return string it's always good to have a `parseInt` before doing any mathematical operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an input that asks the user to input an integer. You use `<input type='number'>`

In your script you have defined your variable as `height`, and then in the `console.log()` you define it as `weight`, which doesn't exist.

When trying to pull the value of the input, you use `document.getElementById('weight').value` not just `document.getElementById('weight')`

Answer (score 1):

you would need to get the value property from the html element , which is

```
let weight= document.getElementById('weight').value;
```

but the value you get is string , if you are doing any type of mathematical operation other than addition then you are good , because javascript will do type coercion which means it will change the string into number , but if you need to do addition then just put height variable inside number() method , which will change the string into number.

i hope this answers your question

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class = input>
<b>Weight </b><input type = '' id = 'weight' value = '180'>
```

```
<script>
  let weight = document.getElementById('weight');
  console.log(weight.value /2.205);
</script>
```